# Set visual state of a FlyoutItem to Selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-shell

I am using Xamarin Forms and default ShellApp. I have FlyoutItems e.g.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png">
    <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

I don't like the default behavior, once clicked on an Item all other pages get poped from NavigationStack, so I changed that.

The problem I am facing now is marking the FlyoutItem as Selected.

I read that it is possible using VisualStateManager, but I don't know how to get the VisualElement and change its VisualState.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small example for your reference：

The following code defines two states for the left menu bar. It displays red in the normal state, and changes to green in the select state.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FlyoutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HeightRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=50}" Style="{StaticResource FlyoutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:OnPlatform Android=54, iOS=50}"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HeightRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=24, iOS=22}"
                WidthRequest="{x:OnPlatform Android=24, iOS=22}">
            </Image>
            <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                    FontSize="{x:OnPlatform Android=14, iOS=Small}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1">
                <Label.TextColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="#D2000000" />
                        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Label.TextColor>
                <Label.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Label.Margin>
                <Label.FontFamily>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="sans-serif-medium" />
                        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Label.FontFamily>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi, the away I navigate to Browse or About page is by using Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new Browse()), I need a way then so highlight the page on the Flyout.

Comment: Since you use route, it is more convenient to use await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//ItemsPage"); and the current page can be highlighted on the left.

Comment: using GoToAsync pops previous page from stack and the default behavior of hamburger menu is to open Flyout

Comment: Use your method to not show the hamburger menu.

Comment: that still does not solve the problem that all pages get poped from NavigationStack. 
Is there a way to get Shell.Current.Children? then I can find the Grid and set the VisualState of that Grid

Comment: Does Shell.Current.Children refer to the current page? In fact, you only need to paste my code on the code you provided to achieve it. When it is in the select state, it will turn red.